# Implement Refunds for In-App Purchases on a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

Hello everyone and thanks for opening the question!

I've been looking to find a way to implement refunds for in app purchases inside my client's Flutter App for months without any result.
The app has the ability to purchase coins through IAP, but when a user asks for a refund to Apple or Google an it is approved, the coins remain registered in his/her account
I keep track of the purchases on a Firebase database so I cannot rely on the Past Purchases information given from the app.

Is there a way to detect inside the app when a user asks for a refund or to check if any refund has been requested by the user?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Track Google Play refunds performed by user/google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229960/track-google-play-refunds-performed-by-user-google)